# Why did all the creatures start singing during the "Sound of Silence" scene in "Trolls"?

Tags: trolls-2016

In *Trolls*, there is a scene where Poppy and Branch are going to sleep, and Branch says he wants "silence". So, of course, Poppy starts playing "The Sound of Silence" by Simon and Garfunkel:

Poppy sings this song, accompanied by her guitar... and a bunch of animals and.... are those flowers?

This is the only instance we see of these creatures, though. They don't pop up during "True Colors" or "Can't Stop the Feeling", or "Get Back Up Again". Is there any particular reason they only pop up for "The Sound of Silence"? Or, for that matter, what they *are* in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

They're in the scene as a joke: if you have someone complaining that they don't like an individual singing softly and you want to annoy them, how better than singing with an instrument *and* a large choral accompaniment?

Comment: How better... Fireworks?

Comment: Exactly this, the joke is that he wants silence and she's ostensibly singing a soft ballad with silence as the theme, but it ends up a full-on cacophony of noisy critters.